# productId = data['productId'] KeyError: 'productId' in django

Tags: django, e-commerce

when i added a item to cart it is successfully added by prviding the product id like
Action: add
Productid: 1

But when i make payment it is showing error like
**productId = data['productId']
KeyError: 'productId'**
and cart count also not updated after clicking payment

here is my code

def updateItem(request):

```
data=json.loads(request.body)
print(data)
print("sasi")

productId = data['productId']


action=data['action']
print('Action:',action)
print('Productid:',productId)

customer=request.user.customer
product=Product.objects.get(id=productId)
order,created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,complete=False)
orderItem,created=OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order,product=product)
if action == 'add':
    orderItem.quantity=orderItem.quantity+1
elif action == 'remove':
    orderItem.quantity=orderItem.quantity-1
orderItem.save()
if orderItem.quantity<=0:
    orderItem.delete()
    
return JsonResponse('Item was added',safe=False)
```

Comment: You can debug by printing your `request.body` and seeing if `productId` is included, if it's not then it's an issue with your frontend. I suspect it's there but called `product_id`. You can catch the error by using `data.get('productId')` it will return `None` if nothing is found.

Comment: ssure will try that